# Problems in accessing secure Ejb's

Tags: java, websphere, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1, websphere-8

I am new to `WebSphere`, I have written an `ejb` and have even deployed it. 
But when I try to accesss it.

I am getting the following error. Is the problem is with the bindings or configuring security or realm?

> javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: 
>      SERVER (id=4773e3aa, host=localhost) TRACE START:
>      javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: SECJ0053E: Authorization failed for ??? while invoking (Bean)d365-EB_OFSConnectorService-ejb_jar#d365-ModuleConnectorService-ejb.jar#ModuleConnectorServiceBean processOFS:java.lang.String:1  is not granted any of the required roles: d365user 
>      at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityCollaborator.performAuthorization(SecurityCollaborator.java:626)
>      at com.ibm.ws.security.core.EJSSecurityCollaborator.preInvoke(EJSSecurityCollaborator.java:265)
>      at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.EJBSecurityCollaboratorAdapter.preInvoke(EJBSecurityCollaboratorAdapter.java:82)
>      at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.EJBSecurityCollaboratorAdapter.preInvoke(EJBSecurityCollaboratorAdapter.java:43)
>      at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.notifySecurityCollaboratorPreInvoke(EJSContainer.java:3895)
>      at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.preInvokeAfterActivate(EJSContainer.java:3825)
>      at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.EjbPreInvoke(EJSContainer.java:3046)
>      at com.kaiser.services.ofsconnector.ejb.EJSRemote0SLModuleConnectorServiceBean_8c753384.processOFS(EJSRemote0SLModuleConnectorServiceBean_8c753384.java)
>      at com.kaiser.services.ofsconnector.ejb._EJSRemote0SLModuleConnectorServiceBean_8c753384_Tie.processOFS__CORBA_WStringValue(_EJSRemote0SLModuleConnectorServiceBean_8c753384_Tie.java:1)
>      at com.kaiser.services.ofsconnector.ejb._EJSRemote0SLModuleConnectorServiceBean_8c753384_Tie._invoke(_EJSRemote0SLModuleConnectorServiceBean_8c753384_Tie.java)
>      at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:669)
>      at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:523)
>      at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:523)
>      at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1575)
>      at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doRequestWork(Connection.java:3039)
>      at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2922)
>      at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:64)
>      at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
>      at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
>   SERVER (id=4773e3aa, host=localhost) TRACE END.

I have tried looking for it in google but was not successful in it. suggestions are welcome.

**Updates-1**
In my ejb-jar.xml, security has been defined as

```
 <assembly-descriptor>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>d365user</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <method-permission>
        <role-name>d365user</role-name>
        <method>
            <ejb-name>ModuleConnectorServiceBean</ejb-name>
            <method-name>*</method-name>
        </method>
        <method>
            <ejb-name>ModuleConnectorServiceBeanOMS</ejb-name>
            <method-name>*</method-name>
        </method>           
    </method-permission>
</assembly-descriptor>
```

ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ejb-jar-bnd xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
      <session name="ModuleConnectorServiceBean">
        <resource-ref binding-name="jdbc/t24DataSource" name="jdbc/d365DataSource"/>
        <resource-ref binding-name="jdbc/d365LockingDataSource" name="jdbc/d365LockingDataSource"/>
      </session>

      <session name="ModuleConnectorServiceBeanOMS">
        <resource-ref name="jdbc/d365DataSource" binding-name="jdbc/d365DataSource"/>
        <resource-ref name="jdbc/d365LockingDataSource" binding-name="jdbc/d365LockingDataSource"/>
      </session>
    </ejb-jar-bnd>
```

Comment: If you are still in development, do a quick try by removing access annotation on your relevant EJB method. This will track down the problem to network or (more probably) an invalid user->role binding.

Comment: I have removed the security restrictions and it work. so we can safely say that there is no problem in the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SECJ0053E: Authorization failed for ??? while invoking (Bean)d365-EB_OFSConnectorService-ejb_jar#d365-ModuleConnectorService-ejb.jar#ModuleConnectorServiceBean
 processOFS:java.lang.String:1 is not granted any of the required roles: d365user
```

Looks like your client is not performing correct authentication and is not passing credentials. If this is stand alone client, make sure you are invoking it with the correct config for SSL and CORBA, like this:

```
<java_install_root>/bin/java  
-classpath com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_8.5.0.jar:<list_of_your_application_jars_and_classes> 
-Djava.naming.provider.url=iiop://<your_application_server_machine_name> 
-Dcom.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL=file:///home/user1/ssl.client.props
-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL=file:///home/user1/sas.client.props
<fully_qualified_class_name_to_run>
```

For more details check this [Running the IBM Thin Client for Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tcli_ejbthinclient.html)

Comment: Why are you we using these ssl and sas configuration? I understand that if we are using authentication then we need to provide SSL, but still did not get why we are using SAS, Could you please provide me some information on that?

Comment: @user2900314 If you need authentication to your beans (and you need since you have method-permission entries in the EJB configuration), then both configs (ssl, and Corba) are required. SSL describes settings related to the transport layer, sas.client.props describes settings used by the CSIv2 auth protocol. You can find some more info here: [Authentication protocol for EJB security](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/csec_corba.html).

Answer (score 0):

I see authorization error above. Please check security annotations like @RolesAllowed("roleName") in your ejb or deployment descriptor (ejb-jar.xml) to see what roles used to secure EJB.

You need to map those roles to valid users in user registry (i.e. LDAP). Only valid users will be allowed to access your EJB. You can use admin console to map security roles to users/groups as mentioned below:

*Applications -> WebSphere enterprise applications->  -> Security role to user/group mapping* -> select the appropriate role and clck on *"Map user"* to map users. *Map Special Subject -> All Authenticated in Application's Realm* can be used to give all authenticated users access instead of mapping individual users.

Comment: The Ejb's do not use any annotations. It uses xml based bindings.